# How do we see this ring isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

Let $F$ be a field, and $p(x)\in F[x]$ an irreducible polynomial. Write $R=F[x,y]$.

I am looking for a way to see that $$R/p(x)R\cong (F[x]/p(x)[F[x])[y].$$ This notation is clumsy, so in another notation it means

$$R/p(x)R\cong (F[x]/(p))[y].$$

I do have a way to see it by considering the ring homomorphism $\psi:R\to (F[x]/(p))[y]$,

sending $f(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ih_i(x)y^i$ to $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i(h_i(x)+(p))y^i$. Then the kernel is $p(x)R$, and the isomorphism follows by the first isomorphism theorem for rings.

Is this correct? And is there an alternative way to view it? (I like seeing things from different perspectives.)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's correct. I don't know an alternative way, but I think this is the best way.

Comment: Consider universal properties.

Comment: Any possibility of showing an explicit isomorphism directly, without going through the First Isomorphism Theorem?